# Swift enum raw value: not working with CGFloat = -1.0

Tags: swift, enums, cgfloat

What does this not work?

```
enum Aspect : CGFloat {
    case Clockwise = 1.0
    case Anticlockwise = -1.0
}
```

On Anticlockwise line I'm told that  'raw value for enum case must be a literal'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like a bug. However it seems to work if you omit the decimal part:

```
enum Aspect : CGFloat {
    case Clockwise = 1
    case Anticlockwise = -1
}
```

Comment: Fixed in [Swift 1.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta/Xcode_6.3_beta_Release_Notes.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

The weird thing is that a float with a minus is not a literal, but an expression. So the error message is correct.

From the Swift programming language:

> Unlike with integer literals, negative floating-point numbers are
>   expressed by applying the unary minus operator (-) to a floating-point
>   literal, as in -42.0. The result is an expression, not a
>   floating-point literal.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta). From the release notes:

> Negative floating-point literals are now accepted as raw values in enums.

So your code now compiles and works without problems,
and you can now also define non-integral negative enumeration values,
which was not possible before:

```
enum Aspect : CGFloat {
    case Clockwise = 1.0
    case Anticlockwise = -1.0
    case Strange = -1.25
}
```