# Why enum cannot hold negative decimal in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums

I'm trying to use enum in my project like this:

```
enum ShipShift: CGFloat {
    case Forward = 1
    case Stop = 0
    case Back = -1.0
}
```

but the Xcode throw an error on the third `case` as

```
Raw value for enum case must be a literal
```

then I change my code into:

```
 enum ShipShift: CGFloat {
    case Forward = 1
    case Stop = 0
    case Back = -1
}
```

and Xcode is happy.

But I don't know the real reason.
Why the enum cannot have a case which raw value is a negative decimal?

What should I do if I want the `Back` case equal to `-0.5`?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This has been fixed with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta), compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/28427509/1187415.