# couldn't set enum type as CGFloat

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm trying to define constant with type as `CGFloat`. My syntax is fine and also type is fine. But, I'm getting a weird problem. Please find code below as well the error screenshot.

```
enum CornerRadiusPercent : CGFloat {
    case ImageView = 44.5
    case Status = 40.0
}
```

I've found the similar [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044476/swift-enum-raw-value-not-working-with-cgfloat-1-0), but not helped. Clean the build and compiled, not worked. Also I've replaced the text by clicking on the error red suggestion but keep on showing the same again and again.

[image]

Comment: Have you imported UIKit?

Comment: ... or Foundation ...

Comment: ByDefault, Foundation imported on my class. Now only imported the UIKit. its' worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur because you are not adding `UIKit` framework in you file  just  to add `UIKit` in your file,  error will be vanished.